# Can't set value with local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with local storage. 
My debugger shows me that its storing it locally correctly but for some reason I can't seem to set the value of feed1MainHeader with the stored content?
Any ideas?

```
    <div class="search">


    <input type="text" name="username" id="mySearch" value="">
    <input type="button" class="myButton" value="" onclick="setHeader();">


    </div>
```

Heres my value I'm trying to chage with the above search

```
    <div id="feed1MainHeader" value=""></div>
```

Heres the javascript functions I'm writing for it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">                       


    function setHeader(){

    var header1 = document.getElementById("mySearch");
    localStorage.setItem("header", header1.value);

    }

    function loadHeaders(){


    document.getElementById('feed1MainHeader').value = localStorage.getItem("header");

    }

    loadHeaders();
     </script>
```

Any advice would be amazing.

Comment: Your script probably halts on the errors, like `Document` with capital `D`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, I should probably take a step back from the computer once and a while to let my eyes rest. Changed it but that didn't seem to be the real issue. 

Still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIV elements doesn't have a `value`, you have to use `textContent`, `innerHTML` etc to set the content of the DIV

```
function setHeader() {
    var header1 = document.getElementById("mySearch");
    localStorage.setItem("header", header1.value);
}

function loadHeaders() {
    document.getElementById('feed1MainHeader').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("header");
}

loadHeaders();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe is because you are calling a function before all the document had made, you must use `window.onload`

```
<script type="text/javascript">                       


    function setHeader(){

    var header1 = document.getElementById("mySearch");
    localStorage.setItem("header", header1.value);

    }

    function loadHeaders(){


    Document.getElementById('feed1MainHeader').value = localStorage.getItem("header");

    }

    window.onload = function(){ loadHeaders() };
     </script>
```

Comment: Is there an importance to where this script should sit in my html file then? Tried it where it is and no change:( Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you not just do `window.onload = loadHeaders;`?